How to merge a RTCP.REMP feedback packets in a SFU?
How should handle a SFU receiving REMB packets? For example I have 10 participants that send a camera video in a conference. Every participant receives all video streams.

Should I forward the reduced bitrate of the REMB packet to all senders of a video stream or only to a the referenced ssrc sender?
If I receive a REMB packet from 2 participants then I would use the smallest value. But after which time I can forget an old bitrate value


REMB controls the bitrate. If you are not using simulcast, you need generate the smallest REMB value as aggregated REMB in order not to overload the downstream client. If you are using simulcast things get a little more complicated as you want to maximize what the sender sends and then use simulcast adaptation in the SFU.
Note that BWE is hop-by-hop so whether such merging makes sense at all is questionable. When using REMB, the SFU should estimate the bandwidth of the upstream by itself and not rely on the downstream clients.

That doesn't answer the question, or I don't understand the concept of REMB. For example: Customer A sent a bandwidth of 100 Kbps 60 seconds ago and customer B has now sent 200 Kbps. Should I still take this old value of 100 Kbps into account after one minute or should I ignore it?

REMB is kinda dual-use. It is used for bandwidth estimation on the receive side and communicating that to the sender but can also be used by the receiver to communicate a maximum bandwidth it would like to receive, similar to b=AS in the SDP.
The feedback should be frequent, if you have not received a recent REMB from the client and are using REMB (and abs-send-time) for BWE that is a sign the client might be dead.

You might find https://www.rtcbits.com/2018/12/sending-packet-loss-feedback-in-webrtc.html relevant. Packet loss but since both that and REMB go into BWE it is related
